# What is the best way to receive unsolicited response from GSM SIM900 in PIC18

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, sim900

I am using `PIC18F2520` and trying to communicate with `GSM SIM900`. I am using UART interrupt to receive data from the GSM. I am saving each byte in rxData. Now most of the commands ends with response `OK`. But there are few commands which does not respond with `OK` like when we receive sms notification from GSM, GSM send following notification

```
 +CMTI: "SM",2
```

Now this response doesn't have any `OK`. How to receive data in this case. In my application I need to check for the received sms. I am using following code:

```
void rx_handler(void)
{
  rxData[index] = ReadUSART();

  if(<some condition>)    //condition to check for sms notification
  {
    rxFlag = 1;        //set flag to process it in main loop

  }
  index++;

PIR1bits.RCIF==0;

}
```

I am getting confused on how to check for the sms notification. Till now for other commands, I was setting condition for OK but this doesnt have any OK response. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Maybe all commands (both the OK responses and unsolicited ones) really end up with a newline ('\n' or '\r' or "\r\n").. Then it will be easy to know when either message ends..

Comment: yes I have tried checking for `\r \n` but what happens is lets say I send `AT\r` so it stops after this command and doesnt wait for response. I checked into the buffer while debugging and found out that it stores ` A T \r  \r \n` so due to last `\r \n` it stops after sending command and doesnt wait for response from sim900

Comment: From the [AT command manual](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.11.pdf): "Commands are usually followed by a response that includes <CR><LF><response><CR><LF>"

Comment: @m.Alin I have added an image. You can see I have send `AT+CMGF?\r` command. After the command it adds `\r \n`. So if I check for `\r\n` it will stop here only and will not proceed further

Comment: So just ignore the first `\r\n` and look for the second pair of `\r\n` you receive..

Comment: The SIM900 echos back the command it received, this feature can be disabled. I found it pretty annoying in some cases. But all the same, there will be two  `\r\n` sequences, acknowledge the first and stop and the second as Alin has told you.

Comment: As far as I know, SIM900 has a pin called RI. The module gives a specific signal (described in datasheet) when an unsolicited response is given.

Comment: @BenceKaulics @m.Alin Thanks. I used this double checking method for normal commands and it is working. I just want to confirm that for unsolicited commands, I still have to check for the 2nd pair of `\r\n` or those command will only respond with `\r\n` only.

Comment: I suppose those responses are the same as well, so you should check. Please if you have implemented a working solution, post it as an answer, same for your previous questions.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I have added the code in the answer. Please have a look at the logic. Although its working fine but if you found any mistake, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bence Kaulics  & @m.Alin. I have solved the issue by double checking the `\r \n`. Following is the code I used:

```
volatile int flag = -1;   
volatile int sFlag = 0; 
volatile int uFlag = 0;

void rx_handler(void)
{
    rxData[index] = ReadUSART();

    if(rxData[index]=='\n' && rxData[index-1]== '\r' )
    {
      flag = flag + 1;

      if(flag == 1)    
      {
         sFlag = 1;
      }
    }

}

index++;

PIR1bits.RCIF==0;

}
```

I have used a `flag = -1`. So when I first got `\r \n` value of flag is 0. And again when I got `\r \n` that means we have detected a line end and this is what we are expecting so set `sFlag = 1`. When `sFlag = 1` that means we have received the data and now we can process it.

Comment: Code looks okay. But i think unsolicited reponse have onlt one \r\n. You will also have to add a condition for it.